# asp:Fileupload does not work in ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane

Tags: file-upload, upload, accordion

I am using asp:FileUpload in ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane but it always shows HasFile=false.
I am not using any update panel. The structure of the page is as below.

MAster page-->Master page-->.aspx page-->User control-->User control-->AccordionPane-->File upload control.

I have also set Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data"). still it shows HAsFile=false.
How can I upload image file?

Answer (score 2):

Till now there is one solution in my view... having another small page with only fileupload controll and call it as popup on button click - and place the button inside accordion pane.

its just a way-around... still looking for proper solution....